# Контекст COM отключен C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Во время написания небольшой программы, которая на текущий мониторит подключение/отключение USB-накопителей, возникла проблема при обновлении списка подключенных устройств: при запуске программы функция отрабатывает хорошо, но если я запускаю ее из переопределенного метода WndProc в момент срабатывания событий подключения/отключения, то программы вываливается в экзепшн Disconnected context. Я примерно понимаю суть проблемы, но решить ее пока не удалось. Запускал функцию в отдельном потоке, но в этом случае не получается обновить данные формы.

Обработка событий:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    base.WndProc(ref msg);

    if ((msg.Msg != WM_DEVICECHANGE) || (msg.LParam == IntPtr.Zero))
        return;
    int eventType = msg.WParam.ToInt32();

    DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME volume = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dvi = (DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE));

    if (volume.dbcv_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME) //DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
    {
        switch (msg.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            // New device inserted...
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("A storage device has been inserted; Drive :{0} - {1}", DeviceName, ToDriveName(volume.dbcv_unitmask)), "Detect USB");
                break;

            // Device Removed.
            case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                //MessageBox.Show("Storage has been removed.", "Detect USB");
                break;
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(this.UpdateDeviceList);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Функция обновления:

```
private void UpdateDeviceList()
{
    if (this.uinf == null)
        return;
    if (this.usbList != null) this.usbList.Clear();
    this.usbList = uinf.GetUSBFlashDrive();
    this.bs.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

**UPD1**
Класс с функцией GetUSBFlashDrive():

```
class UsbDeviceInfo
{
    string _serialNumber;
    string _driveLetter;

    public string getSerialNumberFromDriveLetter(string driveLetter) {
        this._driveLetter = driveLetter.ToUpper();

        if(!this._driveLetter.Contains(":")) {
            this._driveLetter += ":";
        }

        matchDriveLetterWithSerial();

        return this._serialNumber;
    }

    private void matchDriveLetterWithSerial() {
        string[] diskArray;
        string driveNumber;
        string driveLetter;

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition");
        foreach (ManagementObject dm in searcher1.Get()) {
            diskArray = null;
            driveLetter = getValueInQuotes(dm["Dependent"].ToString());
            diskArray = getValueInQuotes(dm["Antecedent"].ToString()).Split(',');
            driveNumber = diskArray[0].Remove(0, 6).Trim();
            if(driveLetter==this._driveLetter){
                /* This is where we get the drive serial */
                ManagementObjectSearcher disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
                foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks.Get()) {

                    if (disk["Name"].ToString() == ("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE" + driveNumber) & disk["InterfaceType"].ToString() == "USB") {
                        this._serialNumber = parseSerialFromDeviceID(disk["PNPDeviceID"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string parseSerialFromDeviceID(string deviceId) {
        string[] splitDeviceId = deviceId.Split('\\');
        string[] serialArray;
        string serial;
        int arrayLen = splitDeviceId.Length-1;

            serialArray = splitDeviceId[arrayLen].Split('&');
            serial = serialArray[0];

        return serial;
    }

    private string getValueInQuotes(string inValue) {
        string parsedValue = "";

        int posFoundStart = 0;
        int posFoundEnd = 0;

        posFoundStart = inValue.IndexOf("\"");
        posFoundEnd = inValue.IndexOf("\"", posFoundStart + 1);

        parsedValue = inValue.Substring(posFoundStart + 1, (posFoundEnd - posFoundStart) - 1);

        return parsedValue;
    }

    public string GetCPUId()
    {
        string cpuInfo =  String.Empty;
        string temp = String.Empty;
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if(cpuInfo==String.Empty) 
            {
                cpuInfo = mo.Properties["ProcessorId"].Value.ToString();
            }             
        }
        return cpuInfo;
    }

    public List<string> GetUSBFlashDrive()
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject partition in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + drive["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition").Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject disk in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='"
                      + partition["DeviceID"]
                      + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition").Get())
                {
                    ret.Add(String.Format(new FileSizeFormatProvider(), "{1} {2}, {0:fs} ({3})", disk["Size"], disk["Description"].ToString(), disk["Name"].ToString(), this.getSerialNumberFromDriveLetter(disk["Name"].ToString())));
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;

    }
}
```

Описания экзепшена:

> Контекст 0x1e799e88 отключен.  Для обслуживания запроса к этому COM-компоненту прокси использоваться не будет. Это может привести к повреждению или потере данных. Для исключения этой проблемы убедитесь в том, что все контексты/апартаменты еще существуют до полного завершения приложением использования RuntimeCallableWrappers, представляющих находящиеся в них COM-компоненты.

Крашится вот на этой строке:

```
foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
```

**UPD2**
Спасибо всем за "помощь", проблему решил сам.
Вынес метод в backgroundWorker:

```
    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("UpdateDeviceList. ThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        UsbDeviceInfo uinf = new UsbDeviceInfo();
        e.Result = uinf.GetUSBFlashDrive();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            List<string> usbList = (List<string>)e.Result;
            this.lbDeviceList.DataSource = usbList;
            Debug.WriteLine("UpdateDeviceList completed! ThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А на какой строчке exception? Если в GetUSBFlashDrive - то приведите текст ф-ции... Плюс приведите полный stacktrace исключения.

Comment: Это WinForms? Или откуда берётся WndProc?

Comment: Попробуйте устанавливать флаг и обновляться по-таймеру например. Устройства вы инициализируете то в одном thread, а обновляете в другом - может всётаки всё лучше в одном thread делать?

Comment: *"Я примерно понимаю суть проблемы, но решить ее пока не удалось."* - и в чем же суть проблемы?

Comment: @nick_n_a Добавил в пост листинг класса с функцией и описание экзепшена.

Comment: @VladD Именно, WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за "помощь", проблему решил сам.
Вынес метод в backgroundWorker:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("UpdateDeviceList. ThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    UsbDeviceInfo uinf = new UsbDeviceInfo();
    e.Result = uinf.GetUSBFlashDrive();
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        List<string> usbList = (List<string>)e.Result;
        this.lbDeviceList.DataSource = usbList;
        Debug.WriteLine("UpdateDeviceList completed! ThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```